# iOS app crashes upon opening when switching rotation views

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I am trying to develop an app in XCode that will switch to a new view upon rotation.

Here is the code for `view1controller.h`:

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {}

IBOutlet UIView *portrait;
IBOutlet UIView *landscape;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *portrait;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *landscape;

@end
```

and here is the code for `view1controller.m`:

```
#import "view1controller.h"

@implementation TestViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)))
    {
        self.view = landscape;  
    } else if (((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))) {
        self.view = portrait;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize portrait,landscape;

@end
```

Anyway so the app opens but it crashes upon opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        self.view = landscapeleft;  
    } 

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) 
    {
        self.view = portrait;
    }

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.view = portraitupsidedown;
    }

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.view = landscapeleft;
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: And best of all I didn't have to create 3 .xib files. All in one :)

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets in your header are misplaced.

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *portrait;
    IBOutlet UIView *landscape;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *portrait;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *landscape;

@end
```

---

Also, `@synthesize portrait,landscape;` needs to go under `@implementation TestViewController`

```
@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize portrait,landscape;
```

Notice the UIView's in this image:
[image]

Comment: hmmm. it still seems to crash on launch though :/

Comment: did you connect them in Interface Builder? You need to create 2 separate UIViews in IB.

Comment: Thanks I would leave as many up arrows as I could, but apparently not enough rep.

Comment: Also now I have got this working, I don't know if this is possible, but is it possible to incorporate yet another third view for portrait upside down into this?

Comment: Added another answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)))
{
    [portrait removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:landscape];
} else if (((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))) {
    [landscape removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:portrait];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's no need to call removeFromSuperview.